# fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'fstream.h': No such file or directory

Tags: c++

Hi I'm using visual C++ 2010 Express and I received that error when I compiled this sample program I downloaded "fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'fstream.h': No such file or directory"

```
#include<fstream.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<dos.h>
```

and I tried putting in using namespace std; in the beginning of the code block, but I still received the error

Answer (score 5):

Your sample code is very, very old. Definitely previous century. In this century, we use `<fstream>`. The problem with `<fstream.h>` was that it's not standardized, so there are quite some possibilities about what it can contain. The sample code you downloaded will have made some assumptions, and we can't guess.

In general, since we're talking about old code, it's going to predate `namespace std;`. That is to say, there's likely no `std::ifstream` class but there could be an `ifstream` class. You've commented that `using namespace std;` didn't help, which is the normal hack to get `ifstream` working after including `<fstream>`. It seems you would need another hack, or newer sample code.

Answer (score 3):

Drop `.h` from `<fstream.h>`.

Add `using namespace std;` below the included header files.

Comment: it doesn't work. It just gave me more errors than what I had to begin with.

Comment: that is actually a very poor answer; can you at least explain what the difference is between <fstream> and <fstream.h> ?

Comment: @Pandrei `fstream` exists and `fstream.h` doesn't.  There were compilers 25 years ago that used a non-standard header `fstream.h` but that is not relevant today.

Answer (score 1):

Try without the '.h' at the end:

```
#include <fstream>
```

**Edit:**

It appears some further explanation is in order.

When you have some code that uses fstream for the compiler to understand what that code does it needs the declarations etc. from the fstream header file in the standard library. To tell the compiler to fetch that it needs an include statement. (Note: this explanation is slightly simplified for more info look up C++ preprossesor)

All the imports are handled first. When the compiler can't find file fstream.h it stops. Why? Because without a file that the programmer expects is necessary it is pointless to continue compiling the rest of the code. The code will (most likely) refer to names expected by the programmer to be defined in the missing file.

So when an included file is missing it is not looking any closer at the code you have written.

When you change the include statement to include the right file, the compilation can continue to look more closely at your code. From the comments I read that you get 'more errors'. But the errors are in your code.

As suggested try to fix them yourself. After that create a new question on stackoverflow about specific errors that you don't understand.

Comment: @JethroAngelo  Perhaps that's problems with your code.

Comment: Alright, so how do I fix that without changing my entire code?

Comment: @JethroAngelo Hard to tell, you need to update your question so we can see what error you get now.

Comment: Should I paste my program here and then have you debug it?

Comment: @JethroAngelo try debugging it yourself first. Fix all the compiler errors or warnings, then [see here](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) .

Comment: @MattMcNabb I did debug it, and the only error I received is the one I stated above, fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'fstream.h': No such file or directory.

Comment: @JethroAngelo the answer we are commenting on explains how to fix that, change to `#include <fstream>`. There is no such header as `fstream.h`

Answer (score 0):

I have done this eror.Do not need to remove or add anything else.Only you install turboo C++. it code is turboo code.When i run it there is no eror to show me.
go to bin folder and copy past code and run it. Hope it will help to another.